# getElementByID() parameter explanation

Tags: html, vbscript

Im looking at some automation scripts that were working with a web portal to save a lot of grunt work. The commands for selecting windows and such makes sense to me, however there are a lot of lines that look like

```
Set oSelect = wndw.document.getElementById("pvBody:PageTemplate:innerHolder:ctrlAddPassword:ddlSafename")
```

Or

```
Set oSelect = wndw.document.getElementById("pvBody:PageTemplate:innerHolder:ctrlAddPassword:PasswordProperties:rptRequiredProperties:_ctl2:ctrlRequiredProperties:ddlValue")
```

I understand what the program is doing here: it's selecting an element on the page to work with, but the massive string is confusing to me. I know it probably means nothing without the website itself, but it's all I have to go on myself.

I want to know how to find out what I would put there. Is it as simple as inspecting an element, or do I need to dig into the pages source to find out what it's named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings are IDs of HTML elements. Someone apparently saw fit to choose IDs with some sort of inner structure, presumably to make them easier to find/generate/handle/whatever. From an HTML perspective they're just opaque strings, though. They could just as well be named `"foo"` and `"bar"` as long as they're unique inside the page.

If you need to identify IDs of elements you want to work with, you need to look at either the page source where such an element might look like this:

```html
<select id="pvBody:PageTemplate:innerHolder:ctrlAddPassword:ddlSafename">
  <option value="foo">23</option>
  <option value="bar">42</option>
  ...
</select>
```

or at the code generating the page source (which implements the logic by which the ID is generated).